# What is sample weight in sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

In [probability calibration of classifiers](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/calibration/plot_calibration.html) from scikit-learn, there is a section of codes about [train_test_split](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) which I could not find explanation in documents.

```
centers = [(-5, -5), (0, 0), (5, 5)] X, y =
make_blobs(n_samples=n_samples, n_features=2, cluster_std=1.0,
                  centers=centers, shuffle=False, random_state=42)

y[:n_samples // 2] = 0 
y[n_samples // 2:] = 1 
sample_weight = np.random.RandomState(42).rand(y.shape[0])

# split train, test for calibration 
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test, sw_train, sw_test = \
    train_test_split(X, y, sample_weight, test_size=0.9, random_state=42)
```

1. > What does `sample_weight` in `train_test_split` do?
2. > How does the source code of `train_test_split` process `sample_weight`?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`train_test_split` doesn't just take `x` and `y`. It can take an arbitrary sequence of arrays that have the same first dimension and split them randomly, but consistently, into two sets along that dimension.

In your example there's an array of random weights (one weight per observation) that gets split into training and test arrays, `sw_train` and `sw_test`.

There are many reasons to assign weights to observations. For further discussion, see:

- https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2017/10/02/weight-variables-in-statistics-sas.html
- https://www.r-bloggers.com/linear-models-with-weighted-observations/
- http://www.applied-survey-methods.com/weight.html

Comment: Thank you. But from the source code, I can't see how does `train_test_split` process `sample_weight`.

Comment: It processes `sample weight` in the same way it processes `X` and `y`. It is just another input array.